# Pandoc: LaTeX to HTML - no images shown

Tags: graphics, pandoc

I use `pandoc` to convert my LaTeX file to a plain HTML file. Everything works fine so far. However, images and references are not parsed.

I use

`pandoc guide.tex -o guide.html`

to generate the HTML file.

How can I fix this?

Content of guide.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{picinpar,varioref,floatflt}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}

\graphicspath{ {} }

\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Define the language of the diploma thesis
\selectlanguage{english}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language=Perl,
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

% supress chapter names %
\renewcommand{\chaptername}

% supress numbering %
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

\renewcommand{\Link}[3][]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{registration-step01.jpg}}
    \caption{Registration step one: Capture personnel data}
    \label{fig:registration-step01}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your example compiles fine with `tex4ht`. Try this command `make4ht -u filename.tex`.

Comment: LaTeX parsing is a hard task, Pandoc supports only basic subset of it's syntax, it can't support it fully without the knowledge of all packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198981/converting-tex-to-docx-using-pandoc-why-are-images-not-converted ? (use --extract-media=pandocConversionMedia)